# What exactly are the positioning rules for text in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Here's a very basic piece of code which:

1. Measures the size a piece of text would take.
2. Draws the rectangle which corresponds to this size at coordinates (100, 25).
3. Displays text at coordinates (100, 25).

```cpp
auto str = "Hello, World!";
auto metrix = window->fontMetrics();
auto text = scene->addText(str);
text->setPos(100, 25);
text->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::white);

auto r = metrix.boundingRect(str);
int x, y, w, h;
r.getRect(&x, &y, &w, &h);
scene->addRect(100, 25, w, h, QPen(Qt::white));
```

The `scene` in code is a `QGraphicsScene` with no specific customizations, with the exception of a border set to zero.

I would expect the text to be exactly inside the rectangle. The text is however shifted by a few pixels to the left and a few more pixels to the bottom. Why?

[image]

Comment: @drescherjm: I should have specified that the text is drawn on a `QGraphicsScene`. If I understand correctly, there are no actual limits for the text, i.e. it may not display entirely on the scene, but there shouldn't be word wrapping or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Setting the document margins to `0`, as @NgocMinhNguyen suggested, might seem to work, but it is not a real solution, because you lose the margins. It would be better, if you could get the actual geometry, including margins etc. For that purpose you can use [`QGraphicsTextItem::boundingRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html#boundingRect) instead of `QFontMetrics::boundingRect`.

### Example

Here is a minimal and complete example I have written for you, in order to demonstrate the proposed solution:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QBoxLayout>

struct MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
        QPointF p(100, 25);
        auto *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        auto *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
        auto *textItem = new QGraphicsTextItem(tr("HHHHHHHH"));
        auto *rectItem = new QGraphicsRectItem(textItem->boundingRect()
                                               .adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1));

        textItem->setPos(p);
        rectItem->setPos(p);

        view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
        view->scene()->addItem(textItem);
        view->scene()->addItem(rectItem);

        l->addWidget(view);

        resize(300, 300);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Note:** Please note how I create the rectangle. There is a difference between

```
auto *item = new QGraphicsRectItem(100, 25, w, h);
```

and

```
auto *item = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, w, h);
item->setPos(100, 25);
```

### Result

This example produces the following result:

[image: Text in a bounding rectangle]

Answer (score 2):

`QGraphicsTextItem` is held by `QTextDocument`, which can have a [margin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#documentMargin-prop).
Setting the margin to 0 and the rectangle will be correctly drawn.

```
text->document()->setDocumentMargin(0);
```